# Convert raw SQL to use Laravel Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I got `3 tables`,

```
products, 
categories, 
categories_products (pivot).
```

Each product belongs to one or more category. How can I show products under a specific category

a raw SQL example would be

```
SELECT *
FROM categories_products
INNER JOIN products ON categories_products.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN categories ON categories_products.category_id = categories.id
AND categories.category_name = 'desks'



//App\Products.php
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories', 'categories_products', 'product_id', 'id');

}

//App\Categories.php
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products', 'categories_products', 'category_id', 'id');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

on the top of class write this `use DB;` and then your will be like this

```
$results = DB::table('categories_products')
            ->join('products', 'categories_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->join('categories', 'categories_products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->select('categories_products.*', 'products.*', 'categories.*')
            ->where('categories.category_name','desks')
            ->get();
```

**2nd way is**

```
$results = DB::table('categories_products')
            ->join('products', 'categories_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->join('categories', function($join){
                $join->on('categories_products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->where('categories.category_name','desks')
            })
            ->select('categories_products.*', 'products.*', 'categories.*')
            ->get();
```

**Your relationship should be like this**

```
//App\Products.php
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories', 'product_id', 'id');
}

//App\Categories.php
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Products', 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

**So you can query like this in your controller**
eg: you want to return all products under specific category

**Edited 2** place this relationship in your request model, I just change the keys

```
//App\Products.php
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories', 'categories_products', 'product_id', 'category_id');

}

//App\Categories.php
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products', 'categories_products', 'category_id', 'product_id');

}
```

**and run this query, you will get the results**

```
$result  = \App\Category::with('products')->where('category_name','abc')->get();
```

Comment: how can you use eloquent to do this?

Comment: did you created the Models and relationships? if yes, then tell me the Model names

Comment: App\Products, App\Categories, and Pivot\Categories

Comment: I only have App\Products and App\Categories ... I edited my post

Comment: can you tell me your application structure, so I can give you proper relationships... means like this 1) `Categories` has many `Products` 2) `Products` has many `Images` etc

Comment: It is that each product has one or more categories. Example, product is cup exists under category kitchenware and category glass. I believe it is Products belongsToMany Categores. Categories hasMany Products

Comment: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories', 'product_id', 'id');`
categories table doesn't have a column product_id. `return $this->hasMany('App\Products', 'category_id', 'id');` products table doesn't have a category_id. I am using a pivot table `categories_products` with `product_id` and `category_id` columns

Comment: you mean, you have Pivot table, where you keeping the `category_id` and `product_id` RIght ?

Comment: correct. 
    `Schema::create('categories_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        });`

Comment: I am getting some results now. How do I get it to spit for each product `foreach ($result as $product) {
            echo $product->product_title . "<br>";
        }`

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment, what you actually want?? if you want to return all Categories products, then from my mentioned query remove the `where()` method, you will get all

Comment: Using `$products = Products::where('updated_at', '!=', 2458)->get();`
returns a list of objects that I could do something like `foreach($products as $product) echo $product->productInfo->name;` How can I do that with the result from `$result  = \App\Category::with('products')->where('category_name','abc')->get();`

Comment: you mean this, `\App\Products::with('categories')->get();` will return all products with its categories. for more reference see the Laravel [documentation ](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

Comment: Is it possible to use paginate in here. `$result->products->paginate(10);`?

Comment: Yes, its Possible. its upto your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

If you already have the category instance, you can just access the related products through the relationship attribute.

```
$category = \App\Category::where('category_name', 'desks')->first();
$products = $category->products;
dd($products);
```

If you just have the name of the category, and want to get all the products without first retrieving the category record, you can use the `whereHas()` method:

```
$name = 'desks';
$products = \App\Product::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($name) {
    $query->where('category_name', $name);
})->get();
dd($products);
```

This will get all of the products that have a related category record that matches the constraints assigned in the closure.